# 3 out of 10 items are defective in a factory. Sample of 4 is drawn without replacement

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Let X be the number of defectives in a sample. Show the probability distribution for X random variable.
I am kinda stuck at this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this iteratively since X has a very small range.

$P(X = 0) = 7/10 \times 6/9 \times 5/8 \times 4/7 $

$P(X = 1) = 4 \times 3/10 \times 7/9 \times 6/8 \times 5/7 $

I think that should be enough to figure out the rest since this looks like homework.